# How to PrepareforSegue for multiple objects : UIImageView and audiofile

Tags: iphone, uicollectionview, uistoryboardsegue

```
  - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
   {
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"])
{
    NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [[self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems] objectAtIndex:0];

    // load the image, to prevent it from being cached we use 'initWithContentsOfFile'
    NSString *imageNameToLoad = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d_full", selectedIndexPath.row];
    NSString *pathToImage = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:imageNameToLoad ofType:@"jpg"];
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:pathToImage];

    DetailViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];

    detailViewController.image = image;

    }


}
```

How can i add audio file in prepareforSegue along with UIImageview for destinationViewController

```
audioArray =[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Theme1", @"Theme2", @"Theme3", @"Theme4", nil];

    NSString *filePath = [audioArray objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *audioFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:filePath ofType: @"mp3"];

    NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: audioFilePath];

    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]
                   initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:nil];
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't really get what you mean. You have been passing the UIImage instance to the detailViewController. It is similar if you want to pass other objects.

Comment: Thanks i tried it worked but in every cell it is playing Theme1. No matter which cell you select. Whereas i want it should play Theme1 for first cell Theme2 for second cell and so on

Comment: It is because your filePath is getting the `[audioArray objectAtIndex:0]` which is the first element. Try to make use of the selectedIndexPath.row just like what you did for the image.

Comment: i fixed that by changing it to NSString *filePath = [audioArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]; but now i have to assign this to cell like this cell.image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageToLoad]; how can i assign audioplayer to cell

Comment: Subclass the table view cell and add a property to store the audio file path to it. In the didSelectRowAtIndexPath, allocate the audio player.

Comment: can you show me in code how to do it

Comment: Sorry, but you should try first. It is not that difficult :)